# How can I make the content of pseudo :before indent along with its parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML markup where I inject the text **Chapter** before every `h1` element using the pseudo `:before` selector. I also used the `display:block` property so that the label **Chapter** appears on a separate line. But when I try to apply the `text-indent` style, only the content inserted through the `:before` selector is indented. The content of `h1` element does not move along with the text "Chapter."

### Here is a simplified version of my original HTML.

```css
.chapter{
  background-color:grey;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  text-indent:50px;
}
.chapter:before{
  content:"Chapter 1";
  display:block;
}
.l2{
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
}
.l3{
  background-color:orange;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  clear:both;
}
.container{
  margin:0.3in;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="chapter">
    Getting Started
  </div>
  
  <div class="l2">
  Level 2
  </div>

  <div class="l3">
  Level 3
  </div>
</div>
```

### Actual Result

Only the label "Chapter" is indented.

### Expected Result

The h1 content **Getting Started** should be indented along with the label **Chapter**.

Comment: `Getting Started` only appears to be on a separate line visually. In your code, it's on the same line after the `Chapter 1`. So, `text-indent` is working properly and putting some space before the beginning of the line.  
Note that **there is no h1 content**. If you wrap `Getting Started` in an `<h1>` as I think you intended to do, it gets indented as well, but it's also too big for the block and wraps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2948042/vince. @Vince Thank you. Frankly, I thought when I used "display:block" both the pseudo :before and the "Getting Started" can be targeted separately. I cannot wrap "Getting Started" alone in h1 since I am inserting the "Chapter label" through the :before pseudo selector. Is there a way to insert the label so that it acts like an independent element? Or is there a way to target the Getting Started separately? Any help/input would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. If you wrap `Getting Started` in an `h1` and use `.chapter:before` to add `Chapter 1`, and leave everything else the same, it indents them both and allows you to target them both independently. Then you just need to adjust the font size of the `h1` so that it doesn't wrap within the block.

Comment: Got it. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: @Vince, it did the magic. For me, it was a complex scenario. Your explanation help me understand what is going on. If you could go back and fix it based on your input. Now the label and the h1 element can be indented the way I want it. Thanks a ton. If you had provided the instructions as a solution, I would accept it. There is no way to do that in simple comments. Thanks a ton again.

Comment: I would recommend just using a `padding` in this case. Though I would strongly recommend not using pseudo-element, or CSS attributes in general to contain any text, with the exception of symbols only.
If you already have the possibility to add another element around your `h1` you can simply add a wrapper to the "Chapter 1" instead and avoid using `:before` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative to the other provided answers that may help to solve some of the problems mentioned in comments ...

- Put the chapter title ("Getting Started") into its own block
- Attach the `Chapter 1` prefix to `.chapter .heading:before` instead of the containing block.
- Use `position: relative` on the chapter title block and move it in any direction required. e.g.: `left: 50px`.

```css
.chapter {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.chapter .heading {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}

.chapter .heading:before {
  content: "Chapter 1";
  display: block;
}

.l2 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.l3 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  margin: 0.3in;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="chapter">
    <div class="heading">Getting Started</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="l2">
  Level 2
  </div>

  <div class="l3">
  Level 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I commented earlier, your suggestion did the magic. I already tried it in my actual code. Thank you both, Vince and Hải Bùi,  a lot for taking time out to help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `text-indent` for your pseudo because it only used for only a text, not used for text merged from pseudo and `h1`. So to resolve this issue you can make a space before `h1` to put the `Chapter` text. Hope this help

```css
.chapter{
  background-color:grey;
  height:100px;
  width:400px;
  text-indent: 50px;
}
.chapter:before{
  content:"Chapter 1";
  display:block;
}
.l2{
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  width:400px;
}
.l3{
  background-color:orange;
  height:100px;
  width:400px;
  clear:both;
}
.container{
  margin:0.3in;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="chapter">
    <h1>Getting Started</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="l2">
  Level 2
  </div>

  <div class="l3">
  Level 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That puts the h1 and pseudo in one line. I want them on separate lines. Adding padding will indent the text only to one direction (to the right).

Comment: @antony I've updated snippet, Is that true of your intention?

Comment: Almost, I am looking for the flexibility with indenting to the left or right? For example, if I want the Chapter 1 and Getting Started from over the margin, the padding does not work since padding does not accept - integer values. That's why I was trying to do with the text-indent. Thank you, Hải Bùi.

Comment: @Antony this answer looks to me like what you were trying to do from the start. Hải Bùi fixed the problem I mentioned earlier (`h1` wrapping) by making block wider. `padding` and `text-indent` both use the same units and all units accept integers. If you want to "indent" things from a direction other than the *beginning* (defined by the document language), you need to use something other then `text-indent`. You could try adding the chapter to `.chapter h1:before`. Then use relative positioning on the `h1` to get the spacing you want.